# problemas de redireccionamiento con header y inisio de sesion

Tags: php

estoy intentando hacer un redireccionamiento con **header** en **php** pero no me esta funcionando, la verdad es la primera vez que tengo problemas con esta funcion siempre me ha funcionado bien pero ultimamente al montar mi pagina en la red me esta causando problemas

tambien tengo problemas para iniciar **sesio**n antes esto no me pasaba y la verdad que he buscado en foros web y no encuentro una respuesta clara

este es mi script **php**

```
<?php

require"../class/funciones.php";
require"../class/conexion.php";
require"../core/config.php";

         //obtener parametros
         $titulo_denuncia=$_POST["titulo_denuncia"];
         $direccion=$_POST["direccion"];
         $fecha= date("Y-m-d-H:i:s");

 if($titulo_denuncia!="" && $direccion!=""){

        if(strlen($titulo_denuncia) < 70 ){

             echo"Titulo de la denuncia debe ser de al menos 70 letras";

          }else{

       $stmt_insert=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO denuncias (tipo_denuncia,direccion,fecha)VALUES(?,?,?)");
       $stmt_insert->bind_param("sss", $titulo_denuncia,$direccion,$fecha);
             if($stmt_insert->execute()){

                  session_start();

                 $_SESSION["denuncia"]=$titulo_denuncia;


                header('Location: http://mirandaenloscomentarios.com/denunciantes/');

                 }else{

                     echo"Error: ".mysqli_error($con);
                 }


       }else{


         echo"campo Tiulo es obligatorio";

       }
```

esto es una llamada **ajax** la cual viene de un formulario para luego iniciar sesion de la denuncia del usuario , lo raro es que tengo un **script** parecido a este en el index.php para iniciar sesion como administrador y me funciona a la perfeccion pero este me esta causando problemas .

alguien que me pueda dar una mano nececito tener esto solucionado ya que es un proyecto que esta en marcha y no he podido solucionarlo Gracias de ane mano

Comment: Si a ese **script** lo estás llamando por **AJAX** es mejor que la redirección no la hagas ahí. Lo más óptimo sería devolver una respuesta al **JS** que lanza el **AJAX** y desde ahí ya lanzar la redirección.

Comment: Pero, ¿cuál es el error? ¿Has depurado variables, resultados de consulta, etc?

Comment: ya lo soluccione redirecinando por ajax  gracias de todos modos!